# Qt build menu for touch screen

Tags: c++, qt

i want to build a QT application for windows/android.
I have one mainwindow in which i have different buttons to call submenus, as you can see on the pictures. What do you think is the best implementation for that?

- I thought about replacing the central widget
- Using QStackwidget
- Or open a new widget on the same position and size and close after.

What do you think? Do you have some favourite implementation or do i miss some important?

[image]

---

Edit

My Mainwindow constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_stacked = new QStackedWidget;
    HomeScreen *homescreen=new HomeScreen(m_stacked);
    Control *manual=new Control(m_stacked);
    m_stacked->addWidget(homescreen);
    m_stacked->addWidget(manual);

    this->setCentralWidget(m_stacked);

}
```

Implementation of every Screen

```
class HomeScreen : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit HomeScreen(QStackedWidget* stack, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~HomeScreen();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::HomeScreen *ui;
    QStackedWidget *m_stacks;
};

HomeScreen::HomeScreen(QStackedWidget* stack,QWidget *parent) :
    m_stacks(stack),QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::HomeScreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

HomeScreen::~HomeScreen()
{
    delete ui;
}

void HomeScreen::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_stacks->setCurrentIndex(1);
}
```

What is your solution to change the current Widget, inside a widget of the QStackwidget? I used the solution above what do you think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QStackedWidget` was made right for that, I don't see any reason why you should incline to other options. You can always `removeWidget(widget)` and `delete widget;` if you want to free the memory of some rarely used menu.

Edit:

Your code is fine, there can be only a few enhancements made. You can create `enum` for your indexes in some separate header file.

**Option 1:**

If you use only `QStackedWidget` as a parent menu, you can adjust the constructor:

```
HomeScreen(QStackedWidget* parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::HomeScreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

If you'd want to access `QStackedWidget` and change an index, you spare `m_stacks` pointer and use the parent: `dynamic_cast<QStackedWidget*>(parent())->setCurrentIndex(1 /* or enum */);`.

**Option 2:**

Leave index changing to the parent `MainWindow`. Each menu will have a request signal:

```
signals:
    void goToMenuRequest(int index /* or enum */);
```

which you connect to `m_stacked`'s `setCurrentIndex` in the constructor of `MainWindow`.

Not a big things, but It'll make coding easier.

Comment: Thank you, that was only a question if I am on the right way. I added my implementation above. How did u solve the change between the different Stack widgets inside a widget?